# Failed to install tabula-py

Tags: python-3.x, tabula-py

I don't have much of experience with Python and need some help. I'm trying to install different packages with no success. Most recently I tried to install tabula-py using `pip install tabula-py` But I keep getting the same response.

How solve this?

```
Collecting tabula-py
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026AEB39CDC8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/tabula-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026AEB3B0888>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/tabula-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026AEB3BF088>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/tabula-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026AEB3BF888>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/tabula-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000026AEB3BF6C8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/tabula-py/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tabula-py (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tabula-py
```

Comment: which python version are you using?

Comment: I use Python 3 (part of Anaconda)

Comment: Hope you are using.
    Java 7+
    Python 3.5+

Comment: java version "1.8.0_231"  and python version  3.7.4

Comment: visit it https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/

Comment: somehow it doesn't work for me. I pasted above the responce I'm constantly getting. And cannot find the problem. I cannot install any package.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because pip could not connect to pypi.org server and download the necessary package and install it.

First, try to check if you can connect to pypi.org (from cmd or shell):

`ping pypi.org`

If you establish connection through a regular shell, something might be wrong in your internet settings in python3. You may check if you can connect through this script:

```
import urllib.request


with urllib.request.urlopen('http://pypi.org/') as response:
    status = response.status
    if 500 > status >= 400:
        print("Connection Error from Client: " + str(status))
    elif 600 > status >= 500:
        print("Connection Error from Server: " + str(status))
    else:
        print("Connection Successful")
```

If there is a connection problem, consider [downloading a wheel file](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/#files) of `tabula-py` and installing it localy:

`pip install /path/to/tabula_py-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl`

In the case of `No matching distribution found...`:
Check your python version carefully. On some machines you may found more than one version of python, sometimes installed by 3rd party softwares (i.e. Microsoft Visual Studio). Check your pip version using the command:

`pip -V`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did tried to install it localy, but nontheless I still get the same error message: Collecting distro (from tabula-py==1.4.2)
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement distro (from tabula-py==1.4.2) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for distro (from tabula-py==1.4.2)

Comment: What is the output of `pip -V`?

Comment: the output is:      pip 19.2.3 from .....\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Comment: I don't have Microsoft Visual Studio installed. And after several attempts I still don't make any progress. Here is the output of   ping pypi.org  :

Pinging pypi.org [151.101.64.223] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 151.101.64.223:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

Comment: Tochiza, that means that you cannot connect to the server AT ALL. please try connecting to another network or check with your ISP.